# Custom Javascript Regex - Cannot make it work

Tags: regex

I need to accept the following:

- x{1}.xxxxx{1,40}
- x{1}.xxxxx{1,40}-xxxxx{1,40}
- xxxxx{1,40}
- xxxxx{1,40}-xxxxx{1,40}
- xxxx xxxxx xxxxx{words with space between}

My regex is not working...

```
/^([a-z]{1}\.[a-z]{1,40}|[a-z]{1}\.[a-z]{1,40}\-[a-z]{1,40}|[a-z\s]{1,})$/i
```

While

```
/^([a-z]{1}\.[a-z]{1,40}|[a-z]{1}\.[a-z]{1,40}\-[a-z]{1,40})$/i
```

alone is working OK and

```
/^([a-z\s]{1,})$/i
```

is working OK as well...

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Try `^(?:[a-z]\.[a-z]{1,40}|(?:[a-z]\.)?[a-z]{1,40}-[a-z]{1,40}|[a-z\s]+)$`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5V7Gve/1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only disadvantage is that it works with multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following regex:

```
^(([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{1,40}(-[a-z]{1,40})?|[a-z]+( [a-z]+)+)$
```

This solution uses two patterns:

- the first one matches your first four samples:

  - optional first group: `[a-z]{1}\.`
  - mandatory second group: `[a-z]{1,40}`
  - optional third group: `-[a-z]{1,40}`
- the second one matches your last sample:

  - words separated by characters: `[a-z]+( [a-z]+)+)`

These groups will be highlighted separately.

Explanation in detail:

- `^`: start of string
- `([a-z]\.)?`: one alphabetical character + dot (optional group)
- `[a-z]{1,40}`: from 1 to 40 alphabetical characters
- `(-[a-z]{1,40})?`: dash + 1 to 40 alphabetical characters (optional group)
- `[a-z]+`: combination of alphabetical characters
- `( [a-z]+)+`: combination of multiple <space + combination of characters>
- `$`: end of string

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/pc97ZH/1).

Comment: Thank you, it works as requested. To be honest, @The fourth bird answer works too, but you were quicker, answer is shorter and works better (works only with single space).

Comment: @athco The quicker is not correct, and it's the same answer as I posted where only the spaces are different, but it's ok. Here is some green experience stuff.

Comment: @lemon The answers are the same, only you have capture groups which you don't need for a match only. I don't take anything personally, it's just what it is.

Comment: @Thefourthbird If I began from your answer, I would have done your very same mistake. And even if that was actually true, still remains the fact that your answer does not (fully) meet the needs of the author. Telling that `Here is some green experience stuff.` just shows that you're taking it personally.

Comment: You technically posted the same answer, the only difference are the spaces and the groups. The experience is for you so you get more of it.

Comment: I've reviewed your regex at the link you provided, I agree that *technically* it may be considered the same answer, apart from the fact that I didn't use non-capturing groups, yet my last comment is still valid and it is not on me to decide which of the two answers fit better.

Comment: As I said, all is well..it is not a problem. Now let us go and have some more regex fun :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might write the pattern as:

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]\.)?[a-z]{1,40}(?:-[a-z]{1,40})?|[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:[a-z]\.)?` Match an optional char a-z and a dot
  - `[a-z]{1,40}` Match 1-40 chars
  - `(?:-[a-z]{1,40})?` An optional part matching a hyphen and 1-40 chars
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)+` Match 2 or more words with spaces between them
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DPm7jo/1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I had to up-vote for @lenon (see above coment). The only unwanted feature your answer has, is that it works with multiple spaces (yes, it's obvious how to correct it...).